# How to create a defxyz macro in Clojure?

Tags: macros, clojure

I am very new to Clojure and completely new to macro system.
I am writing a task management system in clojure where I send a piece of clojure code as EDN from one node to another.

To make things less messy, I created a macro called deftask where I associate a name with some code that I send as EDN to another node which evaluates and executes it.

```
(defmacro deftask                                                                                                                                                                   
 "Associates identifier with edn form of the code"                                                                                                                                  
 [id task]                                                                                                                                                                          
  `(def ~id (pr-str '~task)))                                                                                                                                                       

(deftask test-task                                                                                                                                                                  
  (tasks.test.task/execute "World!"                                                                                                                                                   
                           10                                                                                                                                                       
                           (ƒ [arg]                                                                                                                                                 
                              (println "Hello " arg))                                                                                                                               
                           (str "Successfully printed message " 10 " times.")))
```

on the subscriber, this edn is converted to code, and then executed. 
However I need to use require and include `tasks.test.task` other wise eval gets an exception while trying to understand `tasks.test.task`.

Is there a better way to define the macro, so that I can pass full qualified name of a function without having such trouble ?

Here is my code at the subscriber side:

```
(defn execute-edn-expression                                                                                                                                                        
  "Evaluates and runs an expression written in Clojure EDN format"                                                                                                                  
  [edn]                                                                                                                                                                             
  (try                                                                                                                                                                              
    (eval edn)                                                                                                                                                                      
    (catch Exception ex                                                                                                                                                             
      (println "Ex: " (.getMessage ex)))))
```

whenever I don't use use require to include `tasks.test.task` there, catch block executes and the message I get is this:

**Ex:  tasks.test.task**

Thats it!

Comment: what does exception say?

Comment: check my update. the exception just shows a message with name of the namespace.

Comment: why don't you define the code chunk with the needed namespace requires inside?

Comment: For anyone wondering: the exception is a `ClassNotFoundException`. And yes, you have to add a `(require 'tasks.test.task)` either to the code  sent by your producer or before evaluation of the form in your consumer. In both cases you can probably create a list of namespaces-to-require programmatically by recursively walking the code (or using zippers) and finding all fully qualified symbols.

Comment: @GuillermoWinkler: my problem is if the subscriber can respond to 100 different task calls, i will have to include the namespace everywhere.

Comment: @xsc: I did add the namespace in the code. see: tasks.test.task/execute

Comment: You added the namespace to the symbol. But in order for it to be resolvable you have to call `(require 'tasks.test.task)` before `(eval ...)`. So, either you write `(deftask test-task (do (require 'tasks.test.task) ...))` or you generate the `require`-statement automatically (see clojure.zip or clojure.walk).

Comment: @xsc Okay.. Thanks. Why dont't you put both of your comments as an answer here?

Comment: @Amogh, how are the tasks sent - over the wire (network)?

Comment: the macro deftask returns an edn encoded format of the code to be executed. which is then sent to the queing server, RabbitMQ in our case, and then those tasks read by subscriber which also has access to tasks.
basically the software has three namespaces, subscriber,publisher and tasks and each node can run either as a subcriber or publisher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid having to `require` every possible namespace in your server handling code, you can add the `require` on the code chunk sent to the server.

Something like this:

```
(deftask test-task    
  (do    
    (require 'task.test.task)                                                                                                                                                          
    (tasks.test.task/execute "World!"                                                                                                                                                   
                           10                                                                                                                                                       
                           (ƒ [arg]                                                                                                                                                 
                              (println "Hello " arg))                                                                                                                               
                           (str "Successfully printed message " 10 " times."))))
```

So each tasks loads the not already loaded namespace it needs.

You can even modify your `deftask` macro and receive as first parameter the namespaces to load.

```
(deftask test-task        
      ['task.test.task 'other.namespace]                                                                                                                                                          
      (tasks.test.task/execute "World!"                                                                                                                                                   
                               10                                                                                                                                                       
                               (ƒ [arg]                                                                                                                                                 
                                  (println "Hello " arg))                                                                                                                               
                              (str "Successfully printed message " 10 " times.")))
```

Or if using fully namespace qualified functions with a deep walk macro automatically detect the namespaces to load.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: I hope you know that an application like that is very vulnerable since you basically allow arbitrary code to be executed. You might thus want to check out sandboxing strategies like those implemented in [clojail](https://github.com/flatland/clojail).

Now, building on top of Guillermo's answer (at the point where I started typing, at least), you could actually generate a list of namespaces to require by traversing the form supplied to `execute-edn-expression` and collecting those symbols that have fully-qualified names:

```
(defn collect-namespaces
  [form]
  (cond (and (symbol? form) (namespace form)) 
          [(symbol (namespace form))]
        (and (sequential? form) (not= (first form) 'quote)) 
          (distinct (mapcat collect-namespaces form))
        :else []))
```

Then you could do something like this (on the client side!) before calling `eval` in your original code:

```
(apply require (collect-namespaces edn))
```

And all required namespaces should be loaded.

Comment: In our case, we are not running arbitrary code coming from the user or any third party system and yes we are thinking of using a sandbox but concern over performance.
We are Anyways also looking at the storm project.